# Spring MVC @Exception handler: how to remove an attribute from session in exception handler using SessionStatus.setComplete()

Tags: session, spring-mvc, attributes

I am using Spring MVC 3 and want to remove an attribute from session using SessionStatus.setComplete() when an exception was thrown.
Here is what I want to do,

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
 public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request,SessionStatus status)
 {
   //log exception;
   // remove the atrribute in the model
   status.setComplete();
   //return to home page;

  }
```

It doesn't work.So how to get SessionStatus in Exception Handler method to remove an attribute using status.setComplete()? Is there another way to remove an attribute from session in Spring MVC?

Comment: SessionStatus.setComplete() does not remove an attribute from the session.  It invalidates ALL of the session.  You need to use the `HttpSession` and call `removeAttribute()`;

Comment: I use Spring annotation \@SessionAttributes to store a form in the session. but httpSession.removeAttribute() doesn't work. It seems httpSession.removeAtrribute() cannot remove an object stored by Spring annotation \@SessionAttributes. Does anyone have the same experience?

Comment: Late to game, but if you encounter this among googling of things, well according to Spring documentation, I don't think SessionStatus is allowed in ExceptionHandler signature at least: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html